# How to disable jQuery Fullcalendar plugin window resizing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, callback, resize, fullcalendar

I'm using the FullCalendar plugin and it's working very well.  I would like to disable the dynamic resizing of the table and its cells when the browser window is resized.  Is that a possibility?

(I noticed in the documentation the 'windowResize' callback fires after the calendar is already resized, so it looks like that won't help.)

Answer (score 1):

To which view are you referring?
Please have a look at the [weekMode](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/weekMode/) property to fix the month and week view to a predefined size.

Also the property [height](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/height/) and [contentHeight](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/contentHeight/) can help you to freeze dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS - just fix the width of the `div` that you are building the calendar in and the calendar will no longer resize with the window. The height, by default, is controlled by the aspectRatio setting of 1.35.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
// Cut: rest of javascript...
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #calendar {
        width: 900px ;
    }
</style>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```